# Calculating total time in a place with SQL Server datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, sum

I am new to SQL and I was wondering if the following is even possible to achieve.

Using SQL Server 2012 I would like to find the total time a given entity has spent in one location in minutes. There are multiple entries for each entity as they may have gone in and out of a given location many times during the day, I just want to find the total time spent in minutes for all the time spent for a given location.

The table has two `datetime` columns that display `Starttime` and `Endtime`, along with location ID and Entity ID.

I have managed to find a way to work out the time difference between `Starttime` and `Endtime` for one event, but I want to sum for all those events in the location to be displayed as total time.

Please let me know if I need to give any more information

Comment: Would you like to have multiple locations (like different areas of an office) or just one (like the office itself)? In the latter case, you can use the minimum datetime as the start time, and maximum endtime as the time they left the location. If the first one, you will have to do this, grouped by each location you wish to mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to calculate the date difference between the locations where the entity had spent time, as below

```
SELECT
*
FROM MyTable
```

Result Values

```
Starttime               Endtime                 LocationID  EntityID
2014-09-23 14:07:43     2014-09-23 16:07:43     2           2
2014-09-23 14:09:03     2014-09-23 20:09:03     3           2
2014-09-23 14:09:51     2014-09-23 21:09:51     8           2
2014-09-23 14:15:10     2014-09-23 21:15:10     8           3
2014-09-23 14:15:16     2014-09-23 17:15:16     8           3
2014-09-23 14:15:23     2014-09-23 22:15:23     4           3
2014-09-23 14:15:32     2014-09-23 15:15:32     5           3
2014-09-23 14:06:26     2014-09-23 14:06:26     1           2
```

Use the below query to get the desired result

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Starttime), MAX(Endtime)) TotalTimeSpentInMinutes,
    LocationID
FROM MyTable
WHERE EntityID = 2
GROUP BY LocationID
```

Result values would be

```
TotalTimeSpentInMinutes LocationID
0                       1
120                     2
360                     3
420                     8
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it worked perfectly! Thanks to everyone else also for the great help

Answer (score 1):

```
select LocationId , SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime,EndTime))
from locationdatetime
group by LocationId
```

[image]