# Working out shift patterns from SQL

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

This problem I face now is giving me a huge headache I would appreciate anyone who has some advice or help.
I have been tasked to extract shift patterns from this table which contains multiple entities, their locations, start time and end time in a given location and total time spent in a given location. I don’t have enough of a reputation to post an image but I will try and write some of the results

```
Name          Location_name     Starttime                  Endtime              TimeInArea
Jason Brown    Kitchen        2014-07-07 18:50:19   2014-07-07 19:07:50           0:17:31
Jason Brown    Dining Room    2014-07-07 19:07:50   2014-07-09 07:12:05          36:04:15
Jason Brown    Corridor       2014-07-09 07:12:05   2014-07-09 07:13:33          0:01:28
```

As it stands if an entity spends more than 5 hours in a given location that means their shift has ended. The entity takes the tracker off in the dining room, before ending the shift, and in the next even is the next time they are picked up again. Sorry I can’t give a clearer example here or if the formatting is off.

The end result is they want to these shift patters for these entities to use for queries and stored procedures. I’m not sure about the right way to go forward with this, change the ETL or there is some function I can create. Please let me know if I left anything out or more information is required, as I am not even sure what questions to ask the business.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you would like to have.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you looking for a way to add the TimeInArea fields together to get the total shift for the day? Can you post an example of the results you'd like to get? From your question, it sounds very do-able. :)

Comment: The maximum TimeInArea is 5 hours/300 minutes. If the calculated difference in minutes is over that, the desire is to set it at the cap? Is that the problem you're attempting to solve? [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990533/calculating-total-time-in-a-place-with-sql-server-datetime)

Comment: Send the image to my mail address (see my profile) and I will upload for you.